# Dependencies Not getting downloaded for WebDriverAgent project

Tags: ios, xcode, selenium, appium-ios

Hi all please guide how to tackle the issue of : WebdriverAgent Project in XCODE.

Following all prerequisite as required after using command : ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d   inside WebDriverAgent

cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/
open .
copy WebdriverAgent folder
cd WebDriverAgent
mkdir -p Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle
./Scripts/bootstrap.sh

It does not install dependencies needed to build the project successfully .

**Terminal** 
uhg@mjmes-MacBook-Pro WebDriverAgent % ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d
Fetching dependencies
*** Checking out RoutingHTTPServer at "v1.0.1"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/xv/68b21k2x0m53d311mdbb8l3w0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.roAw62.log
*** Downloading RoutingHTTPServer.framework binary at "v1.0.1"
uhg@mjmes-MacBook-Pro WebDriverAgent %

This further show issues in the WEbdriveragentLib project with error  : fbresponse file error

[image: xcode]

[image: xcode1]

[image: xcode2]

Answer (score 0):

I re-download the WDAAgent project and did this. It is working for me for the below steps.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent
mkdir -p Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle
sh ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d
```

- Select WebDriverAgentLib > in the Signing section, check Automatically manage signing > select a team.
- On the menu bar, select Product > Build.
- Select WebDriverAgentRunner > check Automatically manage signing > select a team. On the menu bar, select Product > Build.

Comment: thanks for reply but i tried this multiple times but not working , issue remains